# How two types of variable usage behave different

Tags: bash, java, jdk

I have written a bash script which is executing a `.jar` file with some options. Surprisingly, I found out that using variables with different methods results in different behavior.

**Usage 1:**

```
JAR_FILE="my_jar_file.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="-mx4096M"
GC_OPTS="-XX:+UseG1GC"
echo "java "$GC_OPTS" "$JAVA_OPTS" -jar "$JAR_FILE
java $GC_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar $JAR_FILE
```

This is how it will be executed:

```
java -XX:+UseG1GC -mx4096M -jar my_jar_file.jar
```

**Usage 2:**

```
JAR_FILE="my_jar_file.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="-mx4096M"
GC_OPTS="-XX:+UseG1GC"
echo "java "${GC_OPTS}" "${JAVA_OPTS}" -jar "${JAR_FILE}
java ${GC_OPTS} ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar ${JAR_FILE}
```

This is how it will be executed:

```
java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar my_jar_file.jar
```

Where do those middle option come from?

**EDIT:**

I made a mistake. There was a java build step in the middle which I didn't notice before. That build substitutes the variables and the difference is there. So, as @Kusalananda said, there is no difference between `${VAR}` and `$VAR` usages.

I think I should post a new question and ask java experts why variables substitution works this way.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this actually bash or something else (a systemd service file, perhaps?)

Comment: ... or a Makefile?

Comment: @Kusalananda, it is completely bash script.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar in that case, post the actual, complete script you used and how you invoke it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I actually post the complete script (just ignoring an `echo`); but I will make an edit to make the question more clear.

Comment: @Kusalananda, sorry. I made a mistake. There was a java build step in the middle which I didn't notice before. That build substitutes the variables and the difference is there. I think I should post a new question and ask java experts why variables substitution works this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is actually in a shell script and not in something like a Makefile...

There is absolutely no difference in the shell between `$variable` and `${variable}`.  They are interchangeable.

One may use `${variable}` if it's to be expanded as part of a string and the immediately following character is a character that is valid as part of a variable name, for example as in `"${variable}A"`.

So using `${variable}` does not explain the difference that you see.

The only thing that is certain is that `JAVA_OPTS` seems to have a different value in the second invocation.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that `JAVA_OPTS` is getting a different value in the second approach; but I don't know why. I set the variable just a few lines above in both; why using `$JAVA_OPTS` differs from `${JAVA_OPTS}`?